# iOS: How many core-data calls can be made for displaying a screen before it becomes noticeable?

Tags: ios, core-data

How is the performance for CoreData and what are the general performance guidelines? How many core data calls can be made before the it starts impacting performance and usability? I understand that this depends on various factors like schema, number of rows etc. But are there any recommended best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Use instruments following is a good tutorial to use the instruments.
[see](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use same best practices as for all other databases.

1. Make performance tests to find slowest requests.
2. Use SQL indexes.
3. Make fetches in background thread.
4. Use `fetchLimit`, `fetchBatchSize` and `propertiesToFetch` parameters of `NSFetchRequest` class to reduce amount of fetched data.
5. Use `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` run configuration parameter to be possible analyze SQL requests.